# Refreshing Pivot Cache

Tags: excel, vba

Recently, I have been looking for ways to share the same pivot cache among a few pivot table as they all use the same data source. This helps to reduce the excel file size substantially as it would be inefficient to create a new pivot cache of the same data for each and every pivot table.

One solution provided to me was to use a static variable which allows to make a single pivot cache which can be shared by the different sub routines. Here is how it is done.

```
'creates and returns a shared pivotcache object
Function GetPivotCache(pRange As Range) As PivotCache
    Static pc As PivotCache 'static variables retain their value between calls

    If pc Is Nothing Then 'create if not yet created
        Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
                     (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange)
    End If
    Set GetPivotCache = pc
End Function
```

This is the function used to create the share pivot cache among the subroutines. When creating a pivot table, I call this function to check if a pivot cache has already been created. If it has, it will not create a new copy of the pivot cache and would return the one that is already stored in the static variable.

In case any one is wondering how I use it when creating my pivot table, I will provide some more code to better understand how it is utilized.

```
Sub pivottable1()

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet, DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PField As PivotField
    Dim pRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim PTName As String

    SheetName = "MySheetName1"
    PTName = "PivotTable1"
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(SheetName).Delete
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set PSheet = Worksheets(SheetName)
    Set DSheet = Worksheets(1)

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set pRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    Set PCache = GetPivotCache(pRange)  'Here is where I call the function

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TABLENAME:=PTName)

    Sheets(SheetName).Select
        Set PvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTName)
        'Rows
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("TypeCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With PvtTable.PivotFields("NameCol")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

        'Columns
        With PvtTable.PivotFields("CategoryCol")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        'Values
        PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("Values1"), "Value Balance", xlSum
        PvtTable.AddDataField PvtTable.PivotFields("Values2"), "Value 2 Count", xlCount

End Sub
```

The problems with the current piece of code are:

1. Only works on one data source. Scenario: If I have 12 pivot tables, 6 pivot tables share data source 1, the other 6 pivot tables share data source 2. This function would only allow for 1 pivot cache unless I make a duplicate of the same function.
2. Updates on the data source will not be reflected. Scenario: I execute the macro which creates the pivot cache and pivot table. Then I add 10 new records into my data source and use the same macro to refresh the pivot table. These 10 new records will not be included as it still uses the out dated pivot cache.

These problem arises as the pivot cache can only be created once. Once it is created, it sort of "ignores" changes as there is already pivot cache that has been created.

What changes can be done to the GetPivotCache function to help resolve these problem? How does excel know when to create a new pivot cache? I tried recording a macro of creating pivot tables but I do not see anything which looks like a check whether the pivot cache already exists, in order to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a sub that creates a pivotcache using the data source you will specify. Then create another sub that creates a pivot table based on a pivotcache you will specify. For example,

```
Function AddPivotCache(targetWorkbook, targetSource, your args)
    Set AddPivotCache = targetWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(your args)
End Function

Function AddPivotTable(targetCache, your args)
    Set AddPivotTable = targetCache.CreatePivotTable(your args)
End Function

Sub Main()

    Set source1 = your Range(...) / other source types

    Set cache1 = AddPivotCache(ActiveWorkbook, source1)
    pivot11 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)
    pivot12 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)
    pivot13 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)
    pivot14 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)
    pivot15 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)
    pivot16 = AddPivotTable(cache1, your args)

    Set source2 = your Range(...) / other source types

    Set cache2 = AddPivotCache(ActiveWorkbook, source2, your args)
    pivot21 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
    pivot22 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
    pivot23 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
    pivot24 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
    pivot25 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
    pivot26 = AddPivotTable(cache2, your args)
End Sub
```

2- Is always the case, not related with your code. You may prefer using a table instead of a range. Pivot table will reflect the changes in the table. Or you can use power query to get the data from the sheet dynamically, and base your pivot table on it.